# Adding migration options to previously created tables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a migration in rails using this command:

```
rails generate model Group name:string
```

and I ran `rake db:migrate`. Now I want to add some properties to the 'name' like uniqueness and a default value. What are my options to achieve that? do I have to create a new migration for that?

Also let's say I will generate a new model called 'Department' which also has a unique and a default value, is there a way to add these options to the command directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. It sort of depends on a few things, like if you are collaborating with others on this project or it's just you.

If it's just you, and you *don't mind* losing all the `Groups` you have created, then you can `rake db:rollback` and modify your migration file. Note, `rake db:rollback` will only roll back 1 migration. To rollback x number of migrations, then `rake db:rollback STEP=x` will work for you.

If you are collaborating with others (or if this app is in production), I would recommend just creating another migration file.

```
rails g migration update_groups_name

def up
  change_column :groups, :name, :string, default: 'foo'
  add_index :groups, :name, unique: true
end

def down
  change_column_default :groups, :name, nil
  remove_index :groups, :name
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin, would rake db:reset achieve the same thing? Also could you put the default and unique values into the command 'rails g migration' somehow?

Comment: `rake db:reset` runs `db:drop` & `db:setup`. It will drop your entire database. and no, you cannot do it from the command line, you will have to edit your migration file.

Comment: The rails guides chapter on migrations http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html is a good resource here.